# Diagonalization of general SU(N)

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you diagonalize a general unitary operators like SU(N) over some field?
Just as you can diagonalize SO(N) over the complex numbers?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about $\operatorname{SU}_n(k)$ over a general field, as the definition uses complex conjugation.  You would have to restrict to fields equipped with an involution.  It makes more sense to talk about Jordan Normal Form, which exists for matrices over any algebraically closed field, and more generally, if memory serves, over fields which contain all the eigenvalues of the operator.

Comment: I thought he meant a field extension of $\mathbb C$ (of which there aren't any non-trivial ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it over $\mathbb C$.  You can diagonalize over $\mathbb C$, with orthonormal eigenvectors, any matrix which satisfies $AA^* = A^*A$.  (The word used to describe these is "normal").